# GPS creating anchor point by trip mode and time

Tags: gps, gps-time

I was hoping for some help:
I have 200 participants, each with their own GPS file. Each GPS file has 1000s of points, one for every 15 second epoch. I have already cleaned the data through PALMS and have brought the file into arcmap. I would like to merge multiple points that share the same location and trip mode type (e.g., stationary, location number 1, see table attached). The main difference is that the merging needs to be sensitive to time (e.g., there might be 4 points at location 1 as that person visited the location on 4 separate occasions). I don't have tracking analyst, so any help would be much appreciated! The end game is that I need to create 1km anchor points based on places where the track stayed in one location for a large amount of time (e.g., a minimum of two hours, at least three times per week). Could someone suggest how I might do this?
Thanking you.
Erika
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG1OY.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Le8.jpg)

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer if you include some code snippet on which part did you fail. Because asking a question without trying it first makes it hard for us (in this site) to help you

Comment: Hi Koceeng, Apologies, I should have been clearer. I will edit the original post